# Operations on ReadOnlySequence<byte>

Tags: c#, system.io.pipelines

I am doing some experimenting with System.IO.Pipelines and can't work out the best way to convert or use the returned ReadOnlySequence objects.

The only way I have been able to do anything with it is to convert it to an array and then do normal byte functions, eg given the following:

```
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x50, 0x99 };
        ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(byteArray);
```

Do operations on the Buffer:

```
        var theArray = buffer.ToArray();
        // perform normal byte array operations
```

Things I can't figure out how to do without converting to an Array:

```
        foreach(byte theByte in buffer)
            // do something with the byte
```

Testing a particular Byte in the buffer

```
        if(buffer[0] == 0x11)
            ...
```

Copying the byte buffer to a Struct

```
        Marshal.Copy(
```

Is the only way to access the contents of the ReadOnlySequence by turning it back into an array?

Comment: You can try to use `SequenceReader`: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-sequencereader

Comment: Please check first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines#read-streaming-data-scenarios and identify the scenario you want to accomplish. There are various recommended and also problematic code examples there. Perhaps you can add more details to your question.

Comment: I have read that.  I showed three things that I wanted to do.  The first has been answered (although the answer is wrong).  The second is probably irrelevant given the answer to the first.  The third is still outstanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can `foreach` over the `ReadOnlySequence` like this:

```
foreach (var item in buffer)
{
    if (item.Span[0] == 0x01)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's the type?

Comment: The type of `item` here is `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`